# How to return $resource in angularjs with returning just one record (get)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I've got the following code that has the return commented out that actually calls my production web site and works correctly.  It seems to return a single object with a Get when an :id is there and when it is not, it returns an array (as expected).  I want to simulate this with an array or simple object when I'm testing locally.

In the below case (where I have the return not commented, it always returns an array because that is what is in data/sessions.json.  How can I have the $resource point at an object when :id is specified in the call?

```
angular.module('svccApp')
    .factory('speakerResourceService',['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        //return $resource('/rest/presenter/arrayonly/:id');
        return $resource('data/speakers.json');
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `isArray` option? here is an example

```
.factory('itemsResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
   return $resource('/api/items/:id', { id: '@_id'},
    { 
      'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: false}         
    });
 }])
```

Comment: Where do I pump in the actual record?  I'm currently going down the mocke2e path but for simple stuff, it seems like it's overkill